# Cross-reference latex table in RMarkdown

Tags: r-markdown, cross-reference

I made a latex table in a Rmarkdown document. Now, I want to refer to this table in my text, but somehow all the options I could find online do not work. If I do `\label{table1}` or `label{tab:table1}` or `\label{tbl: table1}` after the `\begin{table}` command, and I subsequently refer to the table using `\@ref(table1)` or `\@ref(tab:table1}` or `\@ref(tbl:table1}` or `\ref(table1)`, it all does not seem to work. The place in the text where I refer to the table shows questions marks. So, my question is: How do I refer to my latex table in a RMarkdown file?

Comment: You need to show us a simple document containing the table.  There are lots of ways to insert tables, and the answer probably depends on which one you used.